# How To Wait On WIA CommonDialog.ShowAcquisitionWizard Method to Finish?

Tags: c#, wia

I am trying to use WIA for scanning and am running into a little trouble.  I am using the CommonDialog.ShowAcquisitionWizard method as documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630774(v=vs.85).aspx).  The problem is, there is no object returned from the method.  I need to know when the scanning is complete and I have tried multiple ways (Thread) and have failed.  Can someone please suggest a method I should use to determine whether or not the scan is complete and/or the dialog is closed?

My current code:

```
private void DoScan()
{
    WIA.CommonDialog dialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
    Device device = dialog.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType);
    dialog.ShowAcquisitionWizard(device);

    // immediately jumps to this line...
    string test = "is it done?";

    // if i put a breakpoint there, the WIA interface never appears, I have to continue before it will show.
    // so a threading.sleep(5000) won't work...
}
```